wsdl2Java generates different code block from wsdl metadata
I try to implement wsdl2Java via Maven or SoapUI-generation but both of them generate same buggy code.
My maven pom.xml looks like:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.sha</groupId>
    <artifactId>wsdl-server-samples</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>wsdl-server-samples</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.axis</groupId>
            <artifactId>axis</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.axis</groupId>
            <artifactId>axis-jaxrpc</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-discovery</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-discovery</artifactId>
            <version>0.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>axis</groupId>
            <artifactId>axis-wsdl4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.axis</groupId>
            <artifactId>axis-saaj</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- activation+mail: To stop Axis generating WARNING about "Attachment support being disabled" -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
            <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>wsdl4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>wsdl4j</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>axistools-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.4</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-wsdl-java-classes</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <!-- <sourceDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated/src/main/java</sourceDirectory>-->
                            <outputDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/java</outputDirectory>
                            <subPackageByFileName>true</subPackageByFileName>
                            <useEmitter>false</useEmitter>
                            <verbose>true</verbose>
                            <!-- Use your .wsdl location here-->
                            <sourceDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl</sourceDirectory> 
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>

and my wsdl-snippet looks like:
  <complexType name="ArrayOfBilling">
   <complexContent>
    <restriction base="SOAP-ENC:Array">
     <sequence>
      <element name="item" type="ns:Billing" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" nillable="false"/>
     </sequence>
     <attribute ref="SOAP-ENC:arrayType" WSDL:arrayType="ns:Billing[]"/>
    </restriction>
   </complexContent>
  </complexType>

For example, for this case generated-java class looks like:
public final class ArrayOfBillingHolder implements javax.xml.rpc.holders.Holder {
    public Billing[] value;

    public ArrayOfBillingHolder() {
    }

    public ArrayOfBillingHolder(borc.Billing[] value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

}

But it should return as public Billing[] item; so element name is ignored (should be item but it was value). Any suggestion?
